# Imagemagick - check if top line contains any black pixel

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a white jpg file with some black pixels on it.

I'm looking for a way to check if the top line (so where y = 0) contains any black pixels. Is there any way to do it with Imagemagick / convert, or secondly with any other linux command line tool?

I was not able to find any similar topic on google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can crop the top line out and print the darkest (minimum) pixel in that line like this:

```
magick image.png -crop x1+0+0\! -format "%[min]" info:
```

If there is a pure black pixel, it will print 0.

---

I am assuming your image is greyscale, if not, you may want to make it so:

```
magick image.png -crop x1+0+0\! -colorspace gray -format "%[min]" info:
```

---

Note that JPG images are *lossy*, so even if you draw a black pixel (i.e. 0)  in an image, it may show up as a 3 or a 4 after saving. As such, you *may* also want to add a threshold to force all pixels below a certain value to zero (i.e. pure black) and all pixels above the value to pure white:

```
magick image.jpg -crop x1+0+0\! -colorspace gray -threshold 1% -format "%[min]" info:
```

Comment: Well, I'm unsure if these images are called greyscale or not. They're generated with this type of command: convert -size XxY xc:white -fill black -draw "text position_x,position_y SOMETEXT" $FN .

Comment: They are kind of greyscale as far as JPEGs go, but you can include the `-colorspace gray` anyway without harm. Also, `convert` is old v6 style, you should be using `magick -size ...` nowadays. Note if you really have to continue with v6, you will need to replace `magick` in my commands with `convert`.

Comment: Yes, i used convert instead of magick as magick is not there :- . It seems to work. Thanks. And of course I can use the same for the bottom line.

Comment: Yes, use the following to crop the bottom line `convert image.jpg -gravity south -crop x1+0+0\! ...`

Comment: Thanks, this gravity south is more practical.

Comment: Yes, it saves working out the height of the image :-)